# Android HttpURLConnection seems to post nothing?

Tags: android

Any idea why this is not posting any data? All I get back from my PHP page `$_POST` is `array(0){}` or in other words nothing in `$_POST`. `getData()` is a string full of data. I'm trying to switch from the deprecated `DefaultHttpClient`.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                URL u = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                conn.getOutputStream().write(getData().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                conn.connect();

                InputStream content = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(s + "\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
```

Comment: Try to add `conn.getOutputStream().flush();` before `conn.connect();`

Comment: Still nothing posting.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is  -->>

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialogOff.setMessage("Loading Data..");

}
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


    try {

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            data=new String(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
            LatLng point;

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) 
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);




            return true;
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return false;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


    if(result)
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data transfered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialogOff.cancel();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: I was trying to switch away from `DefaultHttpClient`, because it is removed after API 22 and they say it is less efficient: http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: my applications runs perfect and super fast with that approach..sometimes is better to use what you think is better and less complicated !!

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the reminder. `DefaultHttpClient` can be readded to the new API (see link). That was the main reason for me. Since it was removed.